# Spark Cost Based Optimizer with Glue + S3

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have Spark jobs running on EMR cluster. EMR use AWS Glue as Hive metastore. Jobs write data to S3 through EMRFS in parquet format. I read dataframes with Spark SQL with help of [SparkSession#table](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#table-java.lang.String-) method.

*Is that possible to configure [Spark's Cost Based Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/31/cost-based-optimizer-in-apache-spark-2-2.html) (CBO) with AWS Glue?*

AFAIK, Spark CBO stores table-level statistic at meta store. It works with Hive, but doesn't work with Spark default metastore (embedded Derby). So my confusion is based on the question wheather CBO can use Glue metastore, if it's already using Glue as meta-store for Spark SQL. I suppose the answer is yes, but still not sure.

Comment: you can apply whatever CBOs you can apply it in spark, even if you are using the spark inside a glue job.

Comment: @syadav why do you thing so? CBO requires metastore to store editional table's metadata afte `ANALYZE TABLE` command. AFAIK, Glue apply some limitations compared to Hive HCatalog, i.e. see answer below - Hive not support CBO. I'm wondering if Glue support CBO for Spark jobs

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not supported.

> Cost-based Optimization in Hive is not supported. Changing the value
>   of hive.cbo.enable to true is not supported.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-glue.html

Comment: you answered that CBO isn't supported for Hive. But how about Spark SQL? Why do you thing it's the same for Spark?

Comment: Check https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/03/aws-glue-enables-running-apache-spark-sql-queries/ . `Customers can configure their AWS Glue jobs and development endpoints to use AWS Glue Data Catalog as an external Apache Hive Metastore. This allows them to directly run Apache Spark SQL queries against the tables stored in the AWS Glue Data Catalog.` So it is Hive metastore within AWS Glue Catalog that allows  to run Apache Spark SQL Queries.

Comment: @ SandeepFatangare I know, I've been successfully running Spark SQL against Glue during a last year. Your answer says that CBO isn't supported, but your comment says that Glue is Hive metastore. I do not understand how does it follow that CBO is or isn't supported by Glue.